# How to properly inline and use an inline function in C99, correcting link failure?

Tags: c, inline, c99

Doing `cc -std=c99 example.c` on the following simplified `example.c` file:

```
inline void a()
{
}

int main()
{
   a();

   return 0;
}
```

gets me:

> In function `main':
>   example.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to 'a'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

As I understand this has to do with the requirement of C99 standard to demand exactly one more definition for each inline non-static function that is used in cases where the body cannot be inlined? If that is so, I am guessing I could do with `static inline` instead, but I don't want this to bite me later, so what would be the best course of action here? Obviously, I want to stick to C99 and I want to inline some functions. (Yes, I am aware the compiler usually knows what to inline without being told so, but I have my reasons)

Comment: The `inline` keyword is not what you think it is. It's at best a hint to the compiler that this code may be a candidate for being inlined. At worse, it's ignored.

Comment: Can you compile other files via your cc? Maybe problem in compiler.

Comment: Actually I am using '-Winline' so in my case it won't be ignored. Pardon me for not specifying this, but I didn't think someone would be commenting on what `inline` means in C or reacting to that side of the matters. In most other variations of the above, you are of course absolutely right.
@Mihran no, no problem with the compiler. After checking more closely with the C99 specs, I have specified the inline function(s) in question as `static inline` and everything works. I do want to know if I am taking the right steps here though...

Answer (score 6):

Probably you wouldn't have that error when you compile with -O2 or so.

Inline function definitions should go in header files and an `extern inline` *declaration* should go in *one* compilation unit. Do

```
inline void a(void){
 // empty
}

// in just one .c file
#include "the-file.h"
extern inline void a(void);
```

BTW, declaring `a` without `void` is not a prototype.

Comment: ok, that is interesting. how would I proceed if I need the definition of 'a' to use by several translation units?

Comment: @amn, put just the `inline` *definition* in a header file and the `extern inline` declaration in one of the translation units. Beware that you really need a C99 complying compiler for that. Newer gcc e.g would do.

Comment: @JensGustedt I will keep saying this whenever I find someone who claims this, but the source file must contain the definition too.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that this was obvious. Please see my edit.

Comment: Wouldn't simply `void a(void);` also work in the .c file?

Comment: @MichaelMorris, yes, it is just a matter of style. I just think that using `extern` explicitly makes it more obvious that this changes things such that `a` becomes an external symbol of the translation unit.

Comment: I can understand that, but the point that I was getting at was that the `inline` was both unnecessary and confusing when used on the external declaration.

Answer (score 0):

There's no function prototype, that's all, so the function signature is inferred, and inferred wrong. Add "void a();" to the top of the file, and you're all set.

Comment: yes, that works if 'a' is defined in the same single translation unit (which is the case with the example I have given). As soon as I try to 'share' this inline function however by putting its definition into own header and including this header from two or more translation units, it does not work and I get the 'multiple definition of 'a' error instead... What gives?